# Need help getting an elapsed time with a lapse query to work

Tags: mysql

I need help getting a query to work and I'm having trouble conceptualizing it.  Generally I want to get the time it takes for a computer to upgrade to a new OS, minus any periods of time in between that are caused by failures.

Example of the table would be:

```
timestamp                 -  status

2016-07-19 14:25:59.000    Conversion In Progress
2016-07-20 07:38:20.000    Failed - 04
2016-07-26 07:15:59.000    Conversion In Progress
2016-07-26 08:50:39.000    Conversion Successful
```

You can see there is a big gap from when the conversion initially failed and when it was kicked off again.  I want to avoid adding this period of time for reporting purposes.

My query I use right now is this:

```
 SELECT ROUND( AVG((b.ts - a.ts) / 60), 0)
FROM
(
SELECT mach_name, timestamp, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)as ts FROM w10_migration_log where status = 'Conversion In Progress' 
)a INNER JOIN
(
SELECT mach_name, timestamp, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)as ts FROM w10_migration_log where status = 'Conversion Successful'
) b on a.mach_name = b.mach_name
```

Most entries in the log won't have issues to deal with.  Would that matter?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's not surprising you cannot conceptualize the query, because your table structure is not adapted for this type of query. So you need to start by building the correct table structure.

A correct structure for what you are trying to achieve would be:

```
| attempt_number | device | started_at | finished_at | status (success or failure) |
```

With that your query would be extremely straightforward: you could just make a sum of the time difference between `finished_at` and `started_at` for each attempt of each (or a given) computer.

Now that we have figured that out, the best way it so to build a temporary table or a view similar to that structure (or better yet, refactor your table), then simply query from it.

A query more or less like this one will build the view we want:

```
SELECT start.mach_name, start.timestamp as started_at, stop.timestamp as finished_at
FROM w10_migration_log start
join w10_migration_log stop ON stop.timestamp > start.timestamp and stop.mach_name = start.mach_name
where start.status = 'Conversion In Progress'
group by start.timestamp;
```

Then very simply select from this:

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(finished_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(started_at)))
FROM (
   /* directly the previous query, or a view made from the previous query */
);
```

I did a quick test and got `18:47:01` with your data sample.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Your post makes sense, I didn't create the table but I may be able to see about getting it changed.  Regardless, what if there are more than 2 entries in the log?  We have some machines failing 5,6+ times.  This doesn't seem to work for that scenario.

Comment: @spas2k What doesn't work? I'm suggesting one row per attempt, so 2 or 6 or 20 should work exactly the same.